# How do I cascade a style by theme in android

Tags: android, text, coding-style, themes, textview

Basically, I'd like to have a single layout that I can `skin` differently on the theme.  Many examples and entries on this site seem dance around the issue a little so I'm not entirely certain it can be done.  Or I just don't get it.

Here's the concept.

Let's say my app is sports-related.. the app has a default them of 'SportTheme'
I'd like users also to say they want the 'Football' or 'Baseball' theme, and on designated `<TextView>` elements, I'd like the text (defaults to 'Sport') to change to 'Football' or 'Baseball' given the overall theme applied to the `activity`?

in strings.xml

```
<string name="label_sport">Sport</string>
<string name="label_football">Football</string>
<string name="label_baseball">Baseball</string>
```

in activityA.java  - The important thing here is that the theme is set for the activity (or application is fine, too).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_a);

    switch (user.ThemePreference)
    {
        case FOOTBALL_THEME:
            this.setTheme(R.style.FootballTheme);
            break;
        case BASEBALL_THEME:
            this.setTheme(R.style.BaseballTheme);
            break;
        default:
            this.setTheme(R.style.SportTheme);
            break;
    }
}
```

in layout_a.xml

```
...
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tvSport"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:text="@string/label_sport"
   android:style="@style/SportLabel"></TextView>
```

What do I do in themes/styles? Something like this?  The important thing here is the text in the TextView.  I'll be using the same textView in several different activities throughout the application.

```
<theme name="SportTheme" parent="android:Theme" />

<theme name="FootballTheme" parent="SportTheme">
   <item name="android:background">@color/brown</item>
</theme>

<theme name="BaseballTheme" parent="SportTheme">
   <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
</theme>


<theme name="SportTheme.SportLabel">
   <item name="android:text">@string/label_sport</item>
</theme>

<theme name="FootballTheme.SportLabel">
   <item name="android:text">@string/label_football</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</theme>


<theme name="BaseBallTheme.SportLabel">
   <item name="android:text">@string/label_baseball</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</theme>
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To customize your UI with themes you need to define attributes you want to customize inside your themes and use references to these attributes in layouts (e.g. `attr/backgroundColor`).

There're three files in Android sources which are used for this purpose: **attrs.xml**, **styles.xml** and **themes.xml**. If you need some custom attributes for customization then you should declare them in **attrs.xml**. If you're going to use only predefined Android attributes then you don't need to create this file.

```
<declare-styleable name="SportTheme">
    <attr name="customAttribute" format="color" />
    <attr name="sportLabelStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

The **styles.xml** file is used for defining sets of attribute values. For example you can define different style sets for each widget.

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.SportLabel" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

The **themes.xml** is the main file used for customizing. All themes are usually defined in this file. You can customize something in several ways. For example you can define a default value in the theme and reference it from a layout. Also you can define a reference to a style.

```
<style name="Theme.FootballTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <!-- define value for predefined Android attribute -->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- define value for custom attribute -->
    <item name="customAttribute">@android:color/black</item>
    <!-- define reference to a style -->
    <item name="sportLabelStyle">@style/Widget.TextView.SportLabel</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:textColor="?attr/customAttribute"
    style="?attr/sportLabelStyle" />
```

Notice that style is used without the `android` namespace. That's not a typo.

So if you want to customize your layout using themes you can create several themes and define default values for attributes and attribute sets (styles) and reference these values using

```
?[android:]attr/attributeName
```

Sounds difficult but it's not really. You can use [Android resources](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res/values;h=3da7c8048c57fd8f33755e9d53e47a198ab37651;hb=HEAD) as an example of styling.

Please ask your question if something is not clear.

Comment: Ah! The main key for me was "style="?attr/sportLabelStyle"! :) THX!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog post about [Themes](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/96) which may help you. There is also a series of article on [Custom Controls](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/218) which explains how to create a custom control which is themeable, and this provides additional information about how Android themes work.